# overloading operator for DateTime in .net

Tags: .net, operator-overloading

I **need** to do this in .net because this Date + Number code is from a converted old VB6 code, and these are not typed, so I can't detect when it happens in compilation time. So I'm searching for a solution which I don't need to know when it occurs everywhere in my code.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now + 1
```

to when I receive a number I sum it as days in a date, so I started making this:

```
public static DateTime operator +(DateTime c1, int c2)
{
    return c1.AddDays(c2);
}
```

However it throws this error:

> One of the parameters of a binary operator must be the containing type

How can I achive this Datetime + Int operator?

**EDIT after choosing correct answer:**

1. I'm choosing @Marc Gravell 's answer, because he explained that I want to do is impossible, and he gaves a cleaner solution better than casting unknown types and using `.AddDays` by hand everywhere
2. If you having the same trouble because you can't detect these untyped errors at compile type, @Matt Wilko gave an awesome clue turning turning *Option Strict Off* that VB.Net made at conversion from VB6 to *On*. It won't resolve the problems since it'll detect as errors even when I were doing a Number + Number operation, however it helps a lot to find when a Date + Number would occur at compile time. After solving the Date + Number problems, I'll turn *Option Strict* to *Off* again.

Thank you both guys!

Comment: You should keep Option Strict On all the time. This will save you from encountering strange runtime errors. If there is something you can't do with Option Strict On (e.g. Late Binding) put this code in a partial class and use Option Strict Off at the top of the partial class only.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Just for my specific scenario (it's for a client and I don't have much time to work on this) I'll ignore Option Strict, but If I could , I would do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I **need** to do this in .net

Tough. You can't - at least, not in C#. Sometimes the correct answer is "no". The compiler message tells you why: operators can only be declared on the two types involved, i.e. the operator must be defined on `int` or `DateTime` in this scenario.

You could, for example, add an extension method on `int` so that you could do:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now + 1.Days();
```

By having:

```
public static TimeSpan Days(this int value) {
    return TimeSpan.FromDays(value);
}
```

Comment: I said *need* because this Date + Number code is from an imported VB6 code, and these are not typed, so I can't detect when it happen in compilation time. So I'm searching for a solution which I don't need to know when it occurs everywhere in my code.

Comment: @Wagner and again, that doesn't change reality. You cannot do what you want to; you must change your approach.

Comment: Yes, however I asked here because maybe someone could think in a solution better than searching when it occurs one by one in my code. I have thousands of these operations in the imported code, and it'll be very hard to do your solution by hand since I can't detect at compile time. So, a solution that isn't doing one by one is really impossible, and I have to deal with that?

Comment: @Wagner yes, basically

Answer (score 1):

Your VB6 code is using a Recordset (which I actually recommend you re-write to use ADO.NET first) - this returns an Object type.

In order to be able to do anything with it you need to cast it to a date:

```
//Simulate the read of the recordset field object
Object dateObject = DateTime.Now;
//cast the object to a date and add a day to it
DateTime date = (DateTime)(dateObject) + TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
```

Comment: One day. However this sum is from an imported VB6 code, and these are not typed, so I can't detect when it happen in compilation time. So I'm searching for a solution which I don't need to know when it occurs everywhere in my code.

Comment: Can you show the VB6 code then - that might give a different solution to the problem.

Comment: The VB6 code is "ARecordset.Field("SomeDate") + 1". When I import it to VB.NET it doesn't throw error at compile time, since Recordset.Field doesn't have a strong type, but at execution it throws the error. But I have THOUSANDS of these in the code, it's very hard to search one by one.

Comment: I bet it *does* throw an error in VB.Net if you have Option Strict switched on

Comment: And you won Matt! The VB.Net conversion did the *Option Stric Off* since this is the only way in VB6. Just turning it to On won't resolve my problem, since all recordset fields + 1 , even when field is numeric will thrown an error at compilation, and typing all RS fields by hand will be more painful, however it'll help to find the DateTime + Number operations, fix only these and turn back to *Option Strict Off*, thanks!